# knockout.js on page load json

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

How can I make this add the json data on page load rather than on button click?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/jWTtb/

```
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function (firstName, lastName) {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable(firstName);
    self.lastName = ko.observable(lastName);

    self.loadJson = function () {
        $.getJSON("http://echo.jsontest.com/firstName/Stuart/lastName/Little",
        function (data) {
            self.firstName(data.firstName);
            self.lastName(data.lastName);
        });
    };

};
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

Comment: Just call `vm.loadJson();`?

Comment: got a fiddle to just demo that answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just add

```
self.loadJson();
```

straight after the code which declares the function, or call

```
vm.loadJson();
```

after you have applied the knockout bindings.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively to @Tim B James's answer, one trick I've seen and that works pretty well is to bind the `loadJson` function to a visible binding, which makes it launch after the page has been loaded.

I've updated your fiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/jWTtb/5/

```
<div data-bind="visible: loadJson() || true">
  <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
  <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just add

```
$(function()
{
    vm.loadJson(); 
});
```

at the end of your code.
that way you will both run the code at page load and still have it on your click. also, you can remove the `data-bind="click: loadJson"` and that will also remove the action on the click button if you really don't need it.

here's a working example. http://jsfiddle.net/jMvMm/1/